# how to get back photo gallery pictures after factory resetting LG phone?

Tags: factory-reset, data-recovery, photos, lg

How can you get back erased photo gallery pictures after factory resetting (by Setup Wizard) LG phone ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled "auto-backup" in Google Photos you can readily restore it from there.

If not you may try to recover photos that were on your memory card using recovery software (undelete/unerase) from your computer.